# How can I quickly and accurately find out if a bone is being used in any driver?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I am studying different rigs and I would like to somehow quickly check whether the selected bone is used in some driver about which I do not yet know.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way might be the Drivers Editor. Open sidebar (N-Panel) and select tab Drivers. Deactivate 'Show Only Selected' in header and expand all channels.
When a driver is clicked the targetbone is displayed in Sidebar > Driver > Bone. This must be done for each driver to see all bones. Not really sexy, I think.

[image]

Let's do it with python.

In posemode the script shows all drivers for the active bone:
Armature:Bone.001
used by: Cube (scale)
used by: Sphere (location)

In object and editmode all bones used by drivers are displayed for selected and not hidden objects:
Armature:Bone (LOC_X,WORLD_SPACE) used by 'Cube' (scale)
Armature:Bone.001 (LOC_X,WORLD_SPACE) used by 'Sphere' (location)
Armature:Bone.001 (ROT_X,LOCAL_SPACE) used by 'Armature.001' (pose.bones["Bone"].location)

```
import bpy

def find_drivers(sel):
    objs = []
    for obj in sel:
        try:
            obj.animation_data.drivers    
        except:
            pass
        else:
            objs.append(obj)
    return objs

if not bpy.context.mode == 'POSE':
    sel = bpy.context.selected_objects      # selected + not hidden objects
    objs = find_drivers(sel)
    driver_list =[]
    for obj in objs:
        for drv in obj.animation_data.drivers:        
            if drv.driver.variables[0].targets[0].id.type == 'ARMATURE':
                obj_transform = drv.data_path
                armature = drv.driver.variables[0].targets[0].id.name
                bone = drv.driver.variables[0].targets[0].bone_target
                transform = drv.driver.variables[0].targets[0].transform_type            
                space = drv.driver.variables[0].targets[0].transform_space
                driver_list.append("%s:%s (%s,%s) used by '%s' (%s)" % (armature, bone, transform, space, obj.name, obj_transform))

else:
    arm = bpy.context.active_object
    bone = bpy.context.active_pose_bone  
    driver_list = ["%s:%s" % (arm.name, bone.name)]
    sel = bpy.data.objects
    objs = find_drivers(sel)    
    for obj in objs:
        for drv in obj.animation_data.drivers:        
            var = drv.driver.variables[0].targets[0]
            if var.id.name == arm.name and var.bone_target == bone.name:    
                driver_list.append(" used by: %s (%s)" % (obj.name,drv.data_path))                               
    
# print list
print("+++ searching drivers +++")
for item in driver_list:
    print(item)
```