# (Blender 3.2) How can I use Python to change the variable ID of the property in a driver?

Tags: python, scripting, drivers, data-blocks

Been searching for an answer to this for quite some time, but haven't been able to connect the missing pieces just yet!

My setup is this:

I have an armature, and an FBX object of a face with animation (Hence forth referred to as Face). I've created drivers on the armature that reference specific shape keys and values on the Face. This is my really cheap and dirty way to do facial motion capture, and I've gotten it working very well at the moment, but I've run into a slight issue. Each new capture I do has a new Face that I have to import. Thankfully, all of the shape keys are named the same, but the actual Key they use is a different number.

For now, I've been plugging in the new key each time I have to import a new Face model, but this takes a lot of time and I'd love to be able to run a script where I plug in the new Key number, and press go and it does it all for me, but have been unsuccessful. The closest I get is being able to get down to the driver itself, but I need a script that does a few things:

1. Checks the selected armature for drivers
2. Checks those drivers to ensure that the variable ID is set
3. Change the variable ID to the correct one for each driver found

The path for the variable and value are all the same as well, I just need to change this one little thing and I'll have saved many hours of time. This is what I've gotten so far (Taken a bit from this post: [How can I quickly and accurately find out if a bone is being used in any driver?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249165/how-can-i-quickly-and-accurately-find-out-if-a-bone-is-being-used-in-any-driver)):

```
import bpy

def find_drivers(sel):
    objs = []
    for obj in sel:
        try:
            obj.animation_data.drivers    
        except:
            pass
        else:
            objs.append(obj)
    return objs

if not bpy.context.mode == 'POSE':
    sel = bpy.context.selected_objects
    objs = find_drivers(sel)
    driver_list =[]
    for obj in objs:
        for drv in obj.animation_data.drivers:
            if drv.driver.variables[0].targets[0].id.type == 'SINGLE_PROP': # Checks if the Variable Property type is set to Single Property
                if drv.driver.variables[0].targets[0].id == 'Key.068': # Check if the ID is set to the previous Key
                    drv.driver.variables[0].targets[0].id = 'Key.094' # Change to the new key
```

Upon trying this though, nothing changes on the armature itself and I don't see any errors either. I'm quite a bit lost at this point, and any info that's out there is outdated as I'm on Blender 3.2, and a lot of coding changed past version 3.0. I'm also quite new to scripting and this is the closest I've gotten to anything touching the drivers on the armature in python, so I wouldn't be surprised if the whole thing was wrong. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, kinda! After a lot of trial and error and help from someone much more advanced than I am, I figured out part of the problem. I actually managed to find an [add-on that does exactly what I needed](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-replace-driver-targets/628307/12), and given that I've been trying to do this for a few months, I'm somewhat just tired of looking at it and want to get started on the nitt-gritty of my animation project. However, I'll go ahead and post all the information I've dug up here for anyone else searching for something like this:

Drivers are normally stored in an object's animation data, which still holds true for bones, but the path to access that is a bit different. We have to tell Blender that we want to access a specific pose object's animation data and drill down to the drivers within that. You can see the hierarchy a bit in the Outliner:

[image: Outliner]

This allows us to access drivers that are located on individual bones, instead of just the armature object.

**The Caveat**

This only works for the first variable in the driver. It is possible to iterate through multiple variables within drivers, but unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how. If you've only got one variable set in each driver, continue!

**Making the change**

Here's how to do this finally! First, we need to set the scene to Pose mode, so that it can more easily reference all of the bones we need, and allow us to select specific bones (But I have them all selected, so omit this if you want)

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
```

Next, select all the bones:

```
bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='SELECT')
```

Now we need to create a variable that references the correct information, but mostly so to make our lives a littler easier when creating the rest of the script. The drivers for individual bones are located in the animation_data, but what makes this different from just regular objects is that we have to use 'pose_object' here instead of object to get the correct path.

```
drvs = bpy.context.pose_object.animation_data.drivers
```

Next, we need to iterate through each driver that was found under 'drvs':

```
for i in drvs:
```

Now we setup another variable to drill down to the actual driver variable. Remember, this is within each individual driver now!

```
driver_var = i.driver.variables[0]
```

From here, you can change whichever bit of information you'd like, depending on the id_type that you want. If you need info on what kind of data you can use here, use the dir() command. I'm looking at changing the specific Shape Key the target variable is using, so in order to do that I have to reference the entire data path of the shape key.

```
driver_var.targets[0].id = bpy.data.shape_keys['Key.068']
```

The "[0]" is a placeholder for the target that each individual driver is using as the script iterates through all the drivers it found. Once you run this, each driver will have the referenced Key set properly.

If you'd like to run checks to ensure that you're only changing ones you want, use this before you change the key:

```
if driver_var.type == 'SINGLE_PROP':
    if driver_var.targets[0].id_type == 'KEY':
```

This checks to ensure that variable type is set to "Single Property", and the target ID Type is set to "Key". For reference, here's documentation on the different [variable types](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.DriverVariable.html#bpy.types.DriverVariable.type) and [target ID types](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/id_type_items.html#rna-enum-id-type-items) you can use.

**The Code**

Finally, here's the code I personally used:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='SELECT')

drvs = bpy.context.pose_object.animation_data.drivers

for i in drvs:

    driver_var = i.driver.variables[0]
    
    if driver_var.type == 'SINGLE_PROP':
        if driver_var.targets[0].id_type == 'KEY':
            if driver_var.targets[0].id != bpy.data.shape_keys['Key.068']:
                driver_var.targets[0].id = bpy.data.shape_keys['Key.068']
```

I hope this somewhat helps any soul that may have been scouring the internet as I have been for a while! I'm just getting into learning python, so please forgive my long winded-ness, but I wanted to type this up for anyone else who might be new as well.